# Undefined error while trying to route to client folder using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to `sendFile` index.html from inside my client directory which is at the same level as my server directory, and getting the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.handle (/myapp/server/routes/routes.js:24:7)
```

This is line 24 of my routes.js:
`res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '../client/dashboard/index.html'));`

**Full function**

```
dashRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log('try to load dashboard');
    // res.render('../index.html');
    // res.send('dashboard!');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '../client/dashboard/index.html'));
});

return dashRouter;
```

**My folder structure:**
[image]

---

Using Express `4.10.0`

Do you know why I'm getting that undefined error on the `res.sendFile` line?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of express?

Comment: Hmm strange, it's `4.10.0` recently I restructured all the folders, but I did the `npm cache clean` and redid `npm install`

Comment: Hmm well first of all I think it would be `path.join(__dirname, '../client/dashboard/index.html');` and in your options the root path is `/somepath../client/dashboard` which also seems fishy but I still don't get the same error when I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the root path variable in sendFile

```
var website = express.Router();
app.use('/website', website);

website.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method, req.url);

    next();
});

website.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var path = 'index.html';
    res.sendfile(path, {'root': '../client/website/'});
    // res.sendfile('../client/website/index.html');
});
```

My HTML is getting rendered again!

Answer (score 6):

The error is painfully simple. The function is called "sendfile" not --what I would expect -- "sendFile".